# psql ignores my PAGER variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, psql

I want to use less as my default pager. Therefore I have `PAGER=less` in my `.bashrc`. It's sourced properly:

```
$ echo $PAGER
less
```

However, psql still uses more if I call it with `psql`. BUT: If I call it with `PAGER=less psql`, psql does use less.

I have no idea why that is. Shouldn't the two calls be identical? `man` for example honors `$PAGER`. I know this because

- `MANPAGER` is not set
- `PAGER=more man more` works as expected
- `PAGER='' man more` disables paging altogether (also as expected)

How do I get psql to recognize my pager setting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `export PAGER=less` in your .bashrc.